# All binary images stopped working when created Ttm Mapping with default value for Relative Url

Tags: web8, dxa, topology-manager, image, dxa-1.6

I have created 3 Ttm Mappings for 3 publications each having unique Relative Url.

- Pub B (PUB TCM_ID 15) Relative url {state1}/{lang}
- Pub C Relative url {state2}/{lang}
- Pub D Relative url {state3}/{lang}

But when I created 4th Mapping for **Publication A (PUB TCM_ID 14)** with Relative url "/". All the images stopped working on the website. In the website(DXA) logs i found that for all binary images published from Publication B(PUB TCM_ID 15) its trying to map it with Publication A (PUB TCM_ID 14)

```
2017-01-19 05:12:55,177 [391] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.molinahealthcare.com:92/media/mppaypremmemt_tcm15-1436.jpg' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
```

Issue will trigger exactly after I published the page **"Publish Settings"** from PUblication A (PUB TCM_ID 14)

**Complete website (DXA) logs pasted below:**

```
2017-01-19 05:12:47,668 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v1.6.0.223 --------
2017-01-19 05:12:47,757 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2017-01-19 05:12:47,759 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider' for interface IContentProvider.
2017-01-19 05:12:47,760 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,988 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,989 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,990 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,990 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,992 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,996 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,997 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.BaseStaticFileManager' for interface IStaticFileManager.
2017-01-19 05:12:50,997 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,096 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ItemList' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,096 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,097 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 's:itemListElement'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,097 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article' has semantic type(s) 's:Article'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,098 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,098 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,098 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Date' as semantic property 's:dateCreated'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,099 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:about'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,099 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ArticleBody' as semantic property 's:articleBody'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,100 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Download' has semantic type(s) 's:DataDownload s:MediaObject'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,100 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:name s:description'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,101 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,101 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,102 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image' has semantic type(s) 's:ImageObject s:MediaObject'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,103 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'AlternateText' as semantic property 's:name'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,103 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,103 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,104 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Place' has semantic type(s) 's:Place'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,105 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Name' as semantic property 's:name'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,105 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,105 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Address' as semantic property 's:address'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,105 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Telephone' as semantic property 's:telephone'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,106 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FaxNumber' as semantic property 's:faxNumber'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,106 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Email' as semantic property 's:email'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,106 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Location' as semantic property 's:geo'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,107 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.YouTubeVideo' has semantic type(s) 's:VideoObject s:MediaObject'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,109 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Teaser, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,109 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-19 05:12:51,110 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2017-01-19 05:12:51,110 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2017-01-19 05:12:52,363 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/config/_all.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:52,435 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/config/core.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:52,452 [356] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/landing' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:53,096 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/mappings/includes.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:53,157 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/mappings/schemas.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:53,211 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/mappings/vocabularies.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:53,248 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,268 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,272 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,272 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,273 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,273 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,314 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/resources/_all.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:53,344 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/resources/core.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:53,767 [356] DEBUG - SmartTarget query returned 2 Promotions.
2017-01-19 05:12:53,800 [356] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/ca/en/system/config/smarttarget.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:53,800 [356] DEBUG - Using Promotion View 'SmartTarget:Promotion'
2017-01-19 05:12:53,830 [356] DEBUG - Page Request for URL 'ca/en/landing' maps to Model [SmartTargetPageModel: 1466 ('Landing | My Site')] with View 'LandingPage'
2017-01-19 05:12:54,031 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LabelsAndLinks`1: 1415] Property 'urllist': data-xpm="1"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,202 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:54,203 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:54,203 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:54,217 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 2756-2755] Property 'Title': 
2017-01-19 05:12:54,219 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Title': data-xpm="5"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,222 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Description': data-xpm="6"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,223 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="7"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,224 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Title': data-xpm="8"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,225 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Description': data-xpm="9"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,226 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="10"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,227 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Title': data-xpm="11"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,228 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Description': data-xpm="12"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,228 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="13"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,248 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [Banner: 1409] Property 'image': data-xpm="15"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,249 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [Banner: 1409] Property 'Title': data-xpm="16"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,250 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [Banner: 1409] Property 'Description': data-xpm="17"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,251 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [Banner: 1409] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="18"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,259 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1468] Property 'Title': data-xpm="20"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,260 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1468] Property 'Components': data-xpm="21"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,260 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1468] Property 'Components': data-xpm="22"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,260 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1468] Property 'Components': data-xpm="23"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,261 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1468] Property 'Components': data-xpm="24"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,268 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1379] Property 'Title': data-xpm="26"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,268 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1379] Property 'Components': data-xpm="27"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,269 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1379] Property 'Components': data-xpm="28"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,269 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 1379] Property 'Components': data-xpm="29"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,304 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:54,305 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:54,305 [356] DEBUG - No semantic mapping found between Schema 1047 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image'. Sticking with model type.
2017-01-19 05:12:54,307 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ComponentLists`1: 2765-2767] Property 'Title': 
2017-01-19 05:12:54,308 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Title': data-xpm="33"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,309 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Description': data-xpm="34"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,309 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="35"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,310 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Title': data-xpm="36"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,311 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Description': data-xpm="37"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,312 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="38"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,313 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Title': data-xpm="39"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,314 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'Description': data-xpm="40"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,314 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [GeneralLink] Property 'LinkTitle': data-xpm="41"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,462 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1416] Property 'Components': data-xpm="43"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,464 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="44"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,465 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="45"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,466 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="46"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,466 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="47"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,467 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1416] Property 'Components': data-xpm="48"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,468 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="49"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,468 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="50"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,469 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="51"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,470 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="52"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,471 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="53"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,472 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="54"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,472 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1416] Property 'Components': data-xpm="55"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,473 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="56"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,474 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="57"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,475 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="58"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,476 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="59"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,477 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="60"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,477 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1416] Property 'Components': data-xpm="61"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,478 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="62"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,478 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1416] Property 'Components': data-xpm="63"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,479 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="64"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,480 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="65"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,481 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1416] Property 'Components': data-xpm="66"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,481 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="67"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,482 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="68"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,483 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="69"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,484 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="70"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,500 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1402] Property 'Components': data-xpm="71"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,501 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="72"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,502 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="73"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,503 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="74"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,503 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1402] Property 'Components': data-xpm="75"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,504 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="76"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,505 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="77"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,506 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="78"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,506 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="79"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,507 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1402] Property 'Components': data-xpm="80"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,508 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="81"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,509 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="82"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,509 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="83"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,510 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="84"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,511 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="85"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,512 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1402] Property 'Components': data-xpm="86"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,513 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="87"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,514 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1402] Property 'Components': data-xpm="88"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,514 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="89"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,515 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="90"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,525 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [LinkChain`1: 1403] Property 'Components': data-xpm="91"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,526 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="92"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,526 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="93"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,527 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="94"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,528 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="95"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,529 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="96"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,530 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="97"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,531 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="98"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,532 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="99"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,533 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="100"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,534 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="101"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,535 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="102"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,536 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [ListOfLinks`1] Property 'UrlList': data-xpm="103"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,546 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1404] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="105"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,546 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1404] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="106"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,547 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1404] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="107"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,547 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1404] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="108"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,548 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1404] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="109"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,560 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1407] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="111"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,561 [356] DEBUG - Rendered markup for Entity [SocialSharingList`1: 1407] Property 'SocialLinks': data-xpm="112"
2017-01-19 05:12:54,640 [362] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,642 [388] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/css/MyTest.css' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,700 [384] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/js/jquery.js' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,808 [365] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,824 [356] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/js/MyTest.js' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,826 [373] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/images/share.png' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,832 [368] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/images/email.png' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,919 [391] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/images/print.png' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:54,986 [362] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/Images/homepageTopBg.png' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,024 [384] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/Images/navBg.jpg' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,120 [388] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/system/config/_all.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:55,174 [388] DEBUG - Binary with URL '/system/config/core.json' is still up to date, no action required
2017-01-19 05:12:55,175 [388] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/MyTestLogo_tcm15-1441.png' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,175 [356] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/ViewPersonalHealthRecord_tcm15-1440.png' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,177 [365] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/CareerHealthNews_tcm15-1435.jpg' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,177 [373] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/SearchDoctor_tcm15-1438.png' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,177 [368] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/ChangeDoctor_tcm15-1437.png' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,177 [391] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/mppaypremmemt_tcm15-1436.jpg' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,229 [388] INFO  - Item '/media/MyTestLogo_tcm15-1441.png/index' not found for Localization '14'
2017-01-19 05:12:55,257 [388] ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes)
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
2017-01-19 05:12:55,261 [388] ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
2017-01-19 05:12:55,305 [373] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/Images/gradientbodybg.jpg' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,351 [368] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/C4HIE2_tcm15-1434.jpg' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,394 [368] INFO  - Item '/media/C4HIE2_tcm15-1434.jpg/index' not found for Localization '14'
2017-01-19 05:12:55,423 [368] ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes)
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
2017-01-19 05:12:55,424 [368] ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
2017-01-19 05:12:55,456 [391] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/Images/global-toolbar-bg.jpg' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,503 [388] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/Images/bodybg.png' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,585 [362] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/media/RequestNewId_tcm15-1439.png' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
2017-01-19 05:12:55,640 [362] INFO  - Item '/media/RequestNewId_tcm15-1439.png/index' not found for Localization '14'
2017-01-19 05:12:55,678 [362] ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes)
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
2017-01-19 05:12:55,679 [362] ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
2017-01-19 05:12:55,707 [373] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.MyTestSample.com:92/ca/en/assets/Images/headerBg.png' maps to Localization [15 ('English')]
```

**Publications snapshot Below**
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that the URLs for media items are wrong (i.e. their URL paths don't start with `/ca/en`. Can you confirm that is the case?

Comment: @RickPannekoek, Hi Rick images path is "\media" and images url is "/media/  in the publication properties for Pub B,C,D and for Pub A i intentionally set this to different values : images path="\master" and images url = "/master/"; but still for image url request which has /media in the url its trying to map it with Pub A (TCM_ID 14); any reason for same ?

Comment: BTW: You should set the Publication Type of you Website Publications to "Website". The Website Master can be a "Site Type" (so you can create new Websites using the Site Wizard).  This is unrelated to your problem, but just an advice.

Answer (score 3):

The "Images URL" (a.k.a. "Multimedia URL") is supposed to be "under" the "Publication URL".

The way you have it configured currently indeed results in images being resolved in context of the `500 Website Master` Publication/Localization, because that is the only one where the Publication URL matches the URL of the images.

So: you should set the "Images URL" of `600 Website CA EN` to `/ca/en/media` (for example).

Note that the "Publication Path" and "Images Path" are only relevant for filesystem based publishing and hence irrelevant for DXA.

Also note that you are currently using *server-relative* URLs, but in SDL Web 8 you can also use *context-relative URLs*. The latter means that the URLs you specify in CM are relative to the URL of the mapping specified in Topology Manager.

For example: if all is well, you have a mapping for Publication `600 Website CA EN` with `RelativeUrl` set to `/ca/en`. This "overlaps" with the Publication (and Images) URLs in CM; if you try to change the Publication URL, you should get an error that is doesn't match the mapping. This is because you are using *server-relative* URLs in CM.

So: it is even better to set Publication URL to an empty string (the URL is already in Topology Manager) and set Images URL to `media` (note: no slash at the start makes it *context-relative* and the *context* is, for example, `/ca/en`).

Answer (score 1):

The cd_dynamic conf resolution happens during application start up. The CdConfigLocalizationResolver (Sdl.Web.Tridion) sorts publications by Path in descending order for / or empty. Based on this sorting logic, you may have to move the publication with an empty path to the last. Publishing will still work but DXA will not be able to resolve the images since "/" finds a match for all publications (A,B,C,D), based on the above sorting logic. Hope it helps!

Comment: `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` and `CdConfigLocalizationResolver` is only used for 2013 SP1; for Web 8 the `CdApiLocalizationResolver` is used (by default) which gets the mappings from CIS.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that he was looking for Web 8+DXA :). If it solves the issue, I will edit my answer to include your comment as well.